# Discord.py Buttons - TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, discord.py

I am new to `discord_components`.
I am getting this type error **[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGZAX.png)**
when i click a button in the message ...
My code is -

```py
@bot.event
async def on_button_click(interaction):
  if interaction.component.custom_id == "support_join":
    await interaction.respond(content=f"https://discord.gg/xyzabcklmn", ephemeral=True)
  elif interaction.component.custom_id == "website_link":
    if interaction.member.guild_permission.manage_guild:
      await interaction.respond(content=f"https://bot_website/guild/{interaction.guild.id}", ephemeral=True)
```

Code of buttons -

```py
guild_join_components = [
  button(label="Join Support Server", style="3", emoji=smart_bot_emoji, custom_id="support_join"),
  button(label="Setup from Website", style="3", emoji=smart_bot_emoji, custom_id="website_link")
]
```

Code of command -

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.reply("this is a test cmd", components=guild_join_components)
```

Please can someone tell that what is this error and how to fix it, do i have a mistake in code or not
If you want more details about this the please comment...

Comment: I HIGHLY recommend NOT using `discord_components` due to its bugs etc. Instead you should use `discord.py`'s v2 if you are looking for buttons/selects. For slash commands I suggest `disnake`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask], and [do not upload images of errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Instead, copy and paste the [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):`, and format it like code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel i use replit, and if i select the error and press `Ctrl + C` then it stops my code. I can't copy it from there, so thats why i used a screenshot...

Comment: There is no reason you *have to* use Replit. However, if you put `replit how to copy and paste` into a search engine, you should find that it is easy to solve that problem. We like self-sufficiency around here.

Answer (score 0):

I got something after i searched a lot -
The code should look like -

```py
async def on_button_click(interaction):
  if interaction.custom_id == "support_join":
    await interaction.respond(content=f"https://discord.gg/xyzabcklmn", ephemeral=True)
  elif interaction.custom_id == "website_link":
    if interaction.user.guild_permission.manage_guild:
      await interaction.respond(content=f"https://bot_website/guild/{interaction.guild.id}", ephemeral=True)

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
  await ctx.reply("Testing buttons:", components=[[button(label="Join support server", style=1, custom_id="support_join"), button(label="Setup from website", style=1, custom_id="website_link")]])
  i = await bot.wait_for("button_click")
  await on_button_click(i)
```